# Swap immune connector

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-design

I need to come up with a swap immune connector for a project of mine, and I can't come up with a simple design. The connector is supposed to connect PCBs of the same kind, however, an upside-down swap in the four ports (ABCD -> DCBA) is possible due to the design. The ports are VCC (12V), GND, DATA (5V) and SELECT (0-5V I/O). Can anyone help suggest a solution?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a non-reversible (e.g. keyed) connector?

Comment: Use an 8-pin connector and connect it ABCDDCBA.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 7-pin connector and wire it as below:

```
A B C D C B A
```

You can't afford to do anything too clever with a mix of 12 V and 5 V supplies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm not able to use more than 4 pins. Would it help to use 12V DATA? If the order was 12V, GND, SELECT, DATA, then at least a short circuit wouldn't be possible, but I don't know, how I'd recognize the data pin and GND/SELECT pin.

Comment: (1) Your question doesn't say that you're not allowed use more than four pins. Edit required. (2) We don't know what's on the SELECT and DATA lines so we can't comment. Put all the relevant information into your question. You haven't replied to Brian's comment.